# What to do if clone is not updated when the original object is changed while using shallow cloning process in Java

Tags: java, clone, copy-constructor, shallow-clone

I have created a cloned reference of an object in shallow cloning using Java. But when I update the object, the string stored in the referenced clone is not updated. why?
The base class is,

```
public class Base {
String name;
int price;


public Base(String a, int b) {
    name = a;
    price = b;
    System.out.println("The " + name + " is " + price + " rupees.");
}

public Base(Base ref) {
    this.name = ref.name;
    this.price = ref.price;
}}
```

The class with main method is,

```
public class ShallowCloning {
String name;
int price;
Base ref;   

public ShallowCloning(String a, int b, Base c) {
    name = a;
    price = b;
    ref = c;
}

public ShallowCloning (ShallowCloning once) {
    this.name = once.name;
    this.price = once.price;
    this.ref = once.ref;
    System.out.println("The " + name + " is " + price + " rupees.");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Base pet = new Base("fennec fox", 8000);
    ShallowCloning obj = new ShallowCloning("Sugar glider", 5000, pet);
    ShallowCloning clone = new ShallowCloning(obj);
    System.out.println(obj.name);
    obj.name = "Dog";
    System.out.println(obj.name);
    System.out.println(clone.name);    //Still getting the previously assigned string.
    System.out.println(obj.ref);
    System.out.println(clone.ref);
}}
```

Is there any way of altering my code to get updated values in this process?

Comment: The clone isn't the same object any more. If you want `clone` to be the same as `obj`, simply use `clone = object;`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of cloning (namely: Creating a **new** but identical instance of an object). If you want all changes to reflect to the other object as well, cloning is not the way to go.

Comment: If I code as,     ShallowCloning clone = obj;    I can still reflect the changes occurring in both the objects.